# How get content from html element in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I can use following code in Google Spreadsheet to retrieve a specific `<span>` element on that html-document.

=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NBIX201218C00125000?p=NBIX201218C00125000";"//td[@data-test='PREV_CLOSE-value']/span")

But this returns the error message that the returned content is empty.

[image: content empty]

So how do I retrieve the content (in this example the text '17.00') of this HTML-element in the spreadsheet?

[image: span-element]

Answer (score 2):

Use `IMPORTFROMWEB` [addon](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) (number of requests are limited in the free plan) to get this.

[image: YF]
XPath used :

```
//td[@data-test='PREV_CLOSE-value']/span
```

Formula in C5 :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(C1;C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of the consent manager on Yahoo, that is shown before you get to the actual page.

[image]

When I downloaded the page, after checked the consent, put in on my server and use your code in Google Spreadsheets it is working.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you did: making a copy of the webpage and putting it on my own server and then I also get what I need, just like you. By the way you added /text(). That is also what I was looking for. However I still cannot retrieve the data from the website directly. I already had a Yahoo account, tried adding a gmail account now, accepted consent page for that account too. But actually, the page can be accessed without being logged in at all.

Comment: Can you retrieve the data directly from the yahoo page?

Comment: You accepted the consent, but Google Spreedsheet can not. This is not always a problem, but Yahoo is redirecting the request from finance.yahoo.com to consent.yahoo.com. I assume that you can not achieve what you like to do with Google Spreadsheet and the importxml function.